# Remove object from array in the Document in Following Code using MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

- The given below is my document, I need to remove comments array of an object from the document, so I can pass the document id from the frontend, with postId.
- I am struct please help me.

```
{
  likes: [],
  _id: 5ea4375f49e4355094073330,
  title: 'abc',
  body: 'abc',
  photo: 'no pic',
  postedBy: 5e9aa457de91831e5c9f5005,
  comments: [
    {
      _id: 5ea437c2a584ce5ac0147da1,
      text: 'sadsadsad',
      postedBy: [Object]
    },
    {
      _id: 5ea437c5a584ce5ac0147da2,
      text: 'sadsadsad',
      postedBy: [Object]
    },
    {
      _id: 5ea437c7a584ce5ac0147da3,
      text: 'sadsadsad',
      postedBy: [Object]
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the specific comment or whole array?

Comment: i need to remove specific comment object  `{
      _id: 5ea437c2a584ce5ac0147da1,
      text: 'sadsadsad',
      postedBy: [Object]
    }` this alone in mongo db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a specific element from the array of `comments` you can use the following query:

```
db.mycollection. updateOne(
       {'_id': ObjectId("5ea4375f49e4355094073330")},
       { $pull: { "comments" : { _id: ObjectId("5ea437c2a584ce5ac0147da1") } } }
);
```

If you want to remove comment object from every element in your collection you can simply remove the first argument from `update`. Something like this:

```
db.mycollection.updateMany(
       { },
       { $pull: { "comments" : { _id: ObjectId("5ea437c2a584ce5ac0147da1") } } }
);
```

Comment: (node:15168) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead. i have already try these things dude, mongo db through error.

Comment: I just update my answer. What kind of errors? The following is warning is not an error. You can read more for deprecation on: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html These queries work fine.

Comment: Arunkumar any luck?

Comment: `Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
         req.params.postId,
        {
          $pull: { "comments" : { _id: req.params.commentId } },
        },
        {
          new: true,
        }
      ).exec((error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(402).json(error);
        } else {
          res.json(result);
        }
      });` this will work

Comment: `findByIdAndUpdate` is doing the same as my given answer, because it's based on `updateOne()`. The thing is that you never mention in your question that you want to create a node.js function. You ask for MongoDB query. So basically my answer is correct. Please consider in the future to ask exactly what you need.